# Create crystal report in webservice method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

OK so I have a SOAP web service that is used by a mobile application, I want to add a new webmethod that creates a report through crystal report and save it in a folder. I don't want to use reports published as webservices, I want my report to be created directly from my webmethod. So how it could be? NB: I am using visual studio 2010 and vb.net language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to download the CR_For_VS package and then use the ReportDocument class to export this to the folder

Edit: Code

You would need to reference the Crystal Libraries in your project to use the ReportDocument Class. The code below should give you a start.

```
  ReportDocument rep = new ReportDocument();
        rep.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Report/Quote.rpt"));

        rep.SetDatabaseLogon(Global.SQLUsername, Global.SQLPassword, Global.SQLServer, Global.SQLDatabase);

        foreach (ReportDocument subRep in rep.Subreports)
        {
            subRep.SetDatabaseLogon(Global.SQLUsername, Global.SQLPassword, Global.SQLServer, Global.SQLDatabase);
        }

        rep.SetParameterValue("QuoteID", SessionStore.Current.CurrentQuoteID);
        rep.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, SessionStore.Current.DownloadPath + "/" + gvrParent.Cells[(int)gvQuotesColumnIndex.QuoteNo].Text + ".pdf");
```

Comment: If you mean to add crystal report directly from .NET as Right Click on my project --> add new Item --> Crystal reports, I can do that, but I don't know what to do after that: how it could be linked to my webmethod inputs ... If you mean something else please give me an example or a link,sorry for demanding but I am very new to crystal reports @Christopher Trevor

Comment: This really should have been a comment not posted as an answer.

Comment: I agree the initial answer was brief but leading someone to finding the answer themselves is worth a lot more than dumping copy and paste coding.

Comment: I understand now that there is nothing special for this report as we are creating it in a webmethod in a webservice. It is just like creating a report for a web app? @ChristopherTrevor